# Android: assigning booleans to dates

Tags: android, date

I am creating an app that keeps track of whether a user has done an activity that day or whether they have not. I need a way to give today's date a value of either true or false which I can then access later. Any ideas?

Comment: Database? HashMap? SharedPreferences?

Comment: I was planning to use an SQLite Database with a column for date and a column for true/false but if you know of an easier way, I am open to that.

Comment: Sounds like a fine solution to me. This might be "easier" with SQLite. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html